# How to generate valid filename with unicode characters for download?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, http-headers, filenames

I add `Content-Disposition` header to generate filename for download.

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml'
self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '.nfo'
```

It works well with English characters, but when the filename contains Russian characters (for ex., `filename = u'Some video file (2014).avi'`) it fails. I tried different combinations of `encode('utf-8')` and `urllib.quote`, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Short answer: There is no interoperable way, as [browser compatibility is a mess](http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/)

Comment: Thanks, @LukasGraf. But what is about URL-encoding? Should I URL-encode the filename?

Comment: In the `Content-Disposition` header field? No. As part of the URL, yes.